# Serial Port ttyS0 and ttyS1 not showing in dmesg

Tags: serial-port

My terminal has 4 Serial ports. I try to find them with command `dmesg | grep tty`. This is what I get:

```
[ 1.317597] serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.317730] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.319571] 00:0c: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.319799] 00:0d: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.320007] 00:0e: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.320213] 00:0f: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
```

So I find only ttyS2 and ttyS3 ...

And when I try the command `setserial -g /dev/ttyS*` I get this result:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3`
```

Why aren't the serial ports ttyS0 and ttyS1 listed in "dmesg"?

Comment: Your dmesg may be truncated because of the kernel buffer limit. You may increase it with the log_buf_len=n kernel boot parameter. What does `dmesg | head -n10` show?

Comment: 'dmesg | head -n10
[] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[] Linux version 2.6.35.13 (xxx@xxx) (gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8) ) #1 SMP Tue May 3 10:17:59 CEST 2011
[]BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[]BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000-000000000009fc00 (usable)
[]BIOS-e820: 000000000009fc00-00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[]BIOS-e820: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[]BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000007fda0000 (usable)
[]BIOS-e820: 000000007fda0000 - 000000007fdae000 (ACPI data)
[]BIOS-e820: 000000007fdae000 - 000000007fde0000 (ACPI NVS)
'

Comment: Can anyone help me to resolve the below issue ?